# Filtering/deleting last column of CSV file

Tags: powershell

I need to filter the last element of CSV row. So in every file the last column.
With my knowledge I made this import to filter and export the last column.

```
(Import-Csv Test.csv -Delimiter "," -Header "R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A") |
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $_.A |
    Export-Csv test1.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

My export file then consists of a duplicate header with ,,,,,,,,, added + every row has ,,,,,,,,, added too.

Is there any better way to either filter the last column or delete it?

**Edit:** here is my input file:

```
R,"S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A"
R,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"S","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","T","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","U","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","V","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","We","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","X","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Y","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Z","AJ3DJF"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","A"
RwieRichard,"Software","Test","Uruguay","22","Waldschutzinitiative","Xander","Ytho","Zahlung","AJ3DJF"
```

Output file:

```
"R,""S"",""T"",""U"",""V"",""W"",""X"",""Y"",""Z"""
"R,""S"",""T"",""U"",""V"",""W"",""X"",""Y"",""Z"",""A"",,,,,,,,"
"R,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""S"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""T"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""U"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""V"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""We"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""X"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Y"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Z"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""A"",,,,,,,,"
"RwieRichard,""Software"",""Test"",""Uruguay"",""22"",""Waldschutzinitiative"",""Xander"",""Ytho"",""Zahlung"",""AJ3DJF"",,,,,,,,"
```

Comment: For the duplicate header; you do not need to specify `-Header` if the input file already has headers.

Comment: Your sample code and input data do not produce the output data you claim they would. They sort of would produce that output if you specified a delimiter other than `,` for the import, though (except that the last double quote would come *before* the trailing commas, not *after*). Also, your CSV already has headers, so you don't need to specify them for the import.

Answer (score 1):

For `-ExcludeProperty` to work you must also specify `-Property`. Also, the argument for the parameter must be just the property name, not `$_.A`.

Change

```
... | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty $_.A | ...
```

to

```
... | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty A | ...
```

---

**Edit:** Judging from your alleged sample output you have a delimiter mismatch between your actual code and data. Either your data is comma-separated and you specified a different delimiter for the import, or you did specify a comma for the import, but your actual data is delimited by a different character. Either way, fix that. If your data is actually comma-delimited you don't even need to specify a delimiter for the import, because `Import-Csv` defaults to `,`.

Also, your data already seems to have headers, so you must not specify the headers during the import.

This should correctly import your CSV if it's comma-delimited:

```
Import-Csv 'test.csv' | ...
```

This should correctly import your CSV if it's semicolon-delimited:

```
Import-Csv 'test.csv' -Delimiter ';' | ...
```